# Bash script to Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to translate a Bash script to Python.
I was wondering what is the equivalent of `folderConfig="${homeDirectory}/conf"` in Python please. Is this a  working directory ?

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, read the descriptions of tags you apply. Explain what you expect as outcome, too, and what your initial research gave you already. Don't expect people to solve your whole programming tasks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) in a shell script (not specific to bash) and can be achieved in Python with string concatenation or string interpolation in f-strings:

```
folderConfig = homeDirectory + '/conf' # string concatenation
folderConfig = f'{homeDirectory}/conf' # f-string
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to obtain a Path object:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Either use the slash operator:
folderConfig = Path.home() / 'conf'

# Or call joinpath to do the same thing:
folderConfig = Path.home().joinpath('conf')

print(folderConfig.as_posix())
```